# How to convert DOMNodeList to DOMDocumentFragment?

Tags: php, xml, dom

Would be nice to know one-liner (or just short function) returning `DOMDocumentFragment` using given `DOMNodeList`. In fact, document fragment is already node list just with some magic attached, but what if I need to apply this magic to an ordinary `DOMNodeList`?

Comment: What is the question here? How to get a fragment from a node list, or how to add *some magic* to a node list?

Comment: How to get a fragment from a node list source. Without actually traversing a list.

Comment: Traversing the list would be the easiest choice, it seems. Is there a reason why you don't want to do that?

Comment: 1) less verbose, easy to read declarative code

Comment: 2) performance. traversing list using php foreach is doomed to be slower than a native c implementation of that logic

Comment: I'll steer clear of 1), but for 2) that's all well and good, if/when there is a native C implementation of that logic available to you.

Comment: TL;DR - writing a function (using a foreach loop) would take 5 lines of nice, easy-to-read and understand code... and get the job done.  That is my suggestion.

Comment: Are you asking because you would like be able to pass a nodelist to saveXML / saveHTML methods? Can you share at which point you actually developed the question?